# Play framework and OSGI

Tags: osgi, playframework

Is it possible to integrate play framework with OSGI to create plugable components? Did someone try it?

Comment: Please explain the reason to put negative. Thanks

Comment: I agree it shouldn't be a negative, I just bumped you up. I haven't seen anything on OSGI and Play yet.

Comment: I tried to read the OSGi standard once and decided it was written by the same morons that came up with J2EE. But then, I might be daft :). So my question - why would you want it? I'm interested in seeing the upside here (and being proven wrong :-))

Comment: I do not  have any experiences in the Play! framework but OSGi frameworks are extremely agile, you can start as many as you want in a single VM, they run inside JEE containers in a WAR, or they run on top as the JEE container. So it should not be very hard to integrate an OSGi framework in any JVM based code.

Comment: @cdegroot I think we could get the best of both worlds, the modularity of the OSGI plus agile development of Play Framework... maybe something like Pax Wicket http://www.ohloh.net/p/6298

Comment: In theory yes. 

Play framework is really an akka application, and version 2.5 can be embedded. Taking this into account you can create a bundle that embeds a Play application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean "create Play modules with OSGi", then no, it's not supported

If you mean "deploy Play as an OSGi module" then no, it's not supported

And to be fair, there's no reason to push its support. You can read [these thoughts](http://www.theserverside.com/news/thread.tss?thread_id=62590) from Spring founder on OSGi, as an example. OSGi would add extra complexity to Play, while the main aim of Play is to be a rapid development platform, simple to use, removing some Java conventions (like Sessions).  It would kind of defeat the purpose.

Comment: On the other hand report-engines like BIRT are OSGI-Bundles. I hope this can be integrated. But I'm unsure if this really touch the question.

Comment: I think if you read carefully OSGi does not add extra complexity, the problem is that Spring (IoC) as we know it requires implementation details of the modules. The question is if strong modularity has an advantage, I think it does, but it requires your code to be modular ...

Comment: @pere-villega Thanks. Very usefull link. I will try something like that to see how behaves this framework.

Comment: Unnecessary OSGi FUD (fear, uncertainty & doubt) here. It is completely untrue that OSGi complicates things.

Comment: @derekm this was answered on 2011, things may have changed in 6 years ;)

Comment: Declarative Services have made things easier (at the expense of magic by action at a distance & by assumed theory of operation in how it works), but I think it's more about exposure. Exposure reveals how easy it really is. I suggest that both Spring Core & CDI 2.0 are steeper learning curves than OSGi, while imparting less runtime dynamism & fewer operational benefits. That said, I'm using CDI 2.0 inside of OSGi bundle implementations. The activator wrappers for OSGi services are pretty small and out of the way, a very tiny portion of your app component, and that's w/o declarative services.

Answer (score 1):

If we're discussing Play **2** then it's definitely worth acknowledging that an important and integral part of Play now is [Akka](http://akka.io/), which could be seen as an alternative to OSGi. Philosophically I think Akka has a lot in common with the core principles of Play and Scala (a functional, stateless, NIO approach), while OSGi is more aligned with the Java EE/Spring camp.

That's not to say that Akka and OSGi are wholly mutually-exclusive: [Akka's documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-modules/1.3.1/modules/osgi.html) suggests you can deploy Akka as an OSGi bundle and create some mutant app which has Akka actors firing up via an OSGi bundle.

But to answer the question, no, Play doesn't do OSGi, but it very much does do Akka.

Comment: Akka alternative to OSGi? Couls you please elaborate on this?

Comment: Akka alternative to OSGi? Could you please elaborate on this? Akka is about solving concurrency using the Actor model (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model). OSGI is about loosely coupled modules offering and using their services/interfaces, about pluging them in and out in the runtime -- simply the loosely coupling. Can you please tell us how these concepts overlaps or even can be alternatives?

Comment: Apologies - I didn't mean to suggest that Akka and OSGi are different implementations of the same thing, only that one _could_ achieve a service-oriented approach using Akka. I have no personal experience, only some research I was doing at the time of my answer. See http://blog.kreuzverweis.com/uncategorized/moving-from-osgi-to-akka-and-why-we-knew-after-5-minutes-that-it-was-a-good-idea/ for somebody else's view on it.

Comment: I have Akka in OSGi working here https://github.com/PhilAndrew/JumpMicro