# Run multiple Play applications in one VM

Tags: osgi, playframework-2.0, apache-karaf

Whenever I run "play run" command, a new JVM is launched which has NettyServer running the play application on default port 9000.

But is any of the below things possible in play 2.0.4?

1. Run one netty server to run multiple play applications in one JVM
2. Run muliple netty server on different ports to run multiple play
   applications in one JVM

I want to deploy multiple play applications in Karaf container (project requirement :)  ) so want them to run in one Karaf VM.

Comment: Short: no, it's not possible. Please have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604641/play-framework-and-osgi) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/play-framework/3weAPmUCv5M). Though there appears to be a [play-osgi](https://github.com/mathieuancelin/play-osgi) module. Haven't tried it, though.

Comment: Its true....tried hard to go through play netty code to figure out how to run multiple play applications in over jvm but play apps are too tightly coupled with netty server so its not possible without re-writing play framework code.